# Can we create Monitor and associate with Pools using the ManagementRoot instance using F5-common-python?

Tags: python, f5

Using REST we create monitor(for instance ltm) :

> [POST] /mgmt/tm/ltm/monitor/$template_name

POST - Body

```
{
    "name": template_name,
    "description": some_description,
    "defaultsFrom": "/Common/{template_name}",
    "destination": "*:*",
    "send": some_send_string,
    "recv": some_receive_string
}
```

and to associate it with Pool,

> [GET] - /mgmt/tm/ltm/pool/~Common~$pool_name/?$select=monitor

Is there a way to achieve it using the Python SDK - https://github.com/F5Networks/f5-common-python?

-- Farhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so the ManagementRoot code I figured is as follows

```
from f5.bigip import ManagementRoot

# Connect to the BIG-IP
mgmt = ManagementRoot("bigip.example.com", "admin", "somepassword")

# To Create HTTP Monitor
mgmt.tm.ltm.monitor.https.http.create(name="some_monitor_name", partition="Common")

# To Create HTTP Pool
mgmt.tm.ltm.pools.pool.create(name='mypool', partition='Common', monitor='some_monitor_name')
```

The above created the monitor and new pool which is then associated.. In case if you forget to pass the monitor to create then you can update is using below code

```
my_pool = mgmt.tm.ltm.pools.pool.load(name='mypool', partition='Common')
# Update the monitor 
my_pool.update(monitor='some_monitor_name')
```

and all set to go :)

-Farhan

Comment: the `https` versus `https_s` really screwed me up.   so for reference  `mgmt.tm.ltm.monitor.https_s.https.exists(name='xxx', partition='Common')`